# Is it possible to programatically set a table row into deletion mode?

Tags: ios

I have a table view where if the user long presses on a row a menu pop up appears, one of the options in the menu is to delete the row.

If the user selects the delete option I'd like to make the deletion button appear just as if the user had side swiped the cell.

Is it possible to set an individual cell into edit/deletion mode? I couldn't see anything from the API.

Answer (score 1):

you can fake the effect of showing only one cell in delete mode. Using this method:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == myEditableCellIndex)   // myEditableCellIndex would 
       return YES;                              // change based what cell you 
                                                // are editing.
    return NO;
}
```

so now whenever you enter editing mode, only that cell would show the editing controls.

hope this helps.

Comment: This will sadly add the spinner pre-control on the left but not the delete button on the right. Though I've yet to find a way to skip straight to the second step.